# "File not found error" when installing using composer

Tags: commerce, installation

I'm running Docker on Ubuntu 18 with a container for MariaDB, Nginx and php-fpm (7.3).
The PHP container has composer installed, and I used it to create a Drupal Commerce project. I can start the Drupal install process using a browser, but after I input the DB settings, the process fails and I get the following error.

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
>   HTTP Result Code: 404
>   Debugging information follows.
>   Path: /core/install.php?profile=commerce_base&langcode=en&id=1&op=do_nojs&op=do
>   StatusText: Not Found
>   ResponseText: File not found.

Increasing the execution time, post time, memory limit, post and upload sizes in the *php.ini* file, as recommended by another user, didn't solve the problem.

Nginx error log contains the following message.

> [error] 6#6: *46 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream'.

The database has tables and data in it, so I know the database credentials are correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think this is Nginx related, look here https://serverfault.com/questions/517190/nginx-1-fastcgi-sent-in-stderr-primary-script-unknown

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it turns out it was an Nginx configuration problem. In my docker-compose.yml file i have:

```
web:
  volumes:
    - '/server/path/to/html:/usr/share/nginx/html'

php:
  volumes:
    - '/server/path/to/html:/var/www/html'
```

In my site.conf file, i had:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME project/$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Not sure why this worked for the initial php files i tested but then failed during the installation. Changing this line to the full path as follows solved the problem for me:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/project/$fastcgi_script_name;
```